# how does `with canvas:` (Python `with something() as x:`) works implicitly in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I just realized there is something mysterious (at least for me) in the way you can add vertex instructions in Kivy with the `with` Python statement. For example, the way `with` is used goes something like this:

```
... some code
class MyWidget(Widget)
    ... some code 

    def some_method (self):
        with self.canvas:
           Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
```

At the beginning I thought that it was just the `with` Python statement that I have used occasionally. But suddenly I realize it is not. Usually it looks more  like this (example taken from [here](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example)):

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
   f.write('Hi there!')
```

There is usually an `as` after the instance and something like and alias to the object. In the Kivy example we don't define and alias which is still ok. But the part that puzzles me is that instruction Rectangle is still associated to the self.canvas. After reading about the `with` statement, I am quite convinced that the Kivy code should be written like:

```
class MyWidget(Widget)
    ... some code 

    def some_method (self):
        with self.canvas as c:
           c.add (Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size))
```

I am assuming that internally the method `add` is the one being called. The assumption is based that we can simply add the rectangles with `self.add (Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size))`

Am I missing something about the `with` Python statement? or is this somehow something Kivy implements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know Kivy, but I think I can guess how this specific construction work.

Instead of keeping a handle to the object you are interacting with (the canvas?), the `with` statement is programmed to store it in some global variable, hidden to you. Then, the statements you use inside `with` use that global variable to retrieve the object. At the end of the block, the global variable is cleared as part of cleanup.

The result is a trade-off: code is less explicit (which is usually a desired feature in Python). However, the code is shorter, which might lead to easier understanding (with the assumption that the reader knows how Kivy works). This is actually one of the techniques of making embedded DSLs in Python.

There are some technicalities involved. For example, if you want to be able to nest such constructions (put one `with` inside another), instead of a simple global variable you would want to use a global variable that keeps a stack of such objects. Also, if you need to deal with threading, you would use a thread-local variable instead of a global one. But the generic mechanism is still the same—Kivy uses some state which is kept in a place outside your direct control.

Comment: you were extremely accurate in pointing me to the existence of [a stack](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/graphics/instructions.pyx#L651) which solves my problem when I thought about a global variable somewhere. Thanks you!

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing *extra* magical with the `with` statement, but perhaps you are unaware of how it works?

In order for any object to be used in a `with` statement it must implement two methods:  `__enter__` and `__exit__`.  `__enter__` is called when the `with` block is entered, and `__exit__` is called when the block is exited *for any reason*.

What the object does in its `__enter__` method is, of course, up to it.  Since I don't have the Kivy code I can only guess that its `canvas.__enter__` method sets a global variable somewhere, and that `Rectangle` checks that global to see where it should be drawing.

Comment: Both of you give me a complementary answer. As you said, the __exit__ and __enter__ are [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/graphics/instructions.pyx#L483) and the global variable is [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/graphics/instructions.pyx#L643) but @liori was extremely accurate in his explanation of the stack which also solves my future questions of the existence of a simple global variable and he was first for a few seconds though. But thanks.

Comment: @toto_tico: actually, mine was first by a whopping six seconds  ;)  Liori, however, has edited his answer and given a much more complete picture.

Comment: To be honest, I feel quite flattered by such quick answers of high profile users. Specially after receiving a Tumbleweed badge. Thanks.